# "sort -h" not working in Redhat 5.9. Any way to upgrade it?

Tags: centos, rhel, sort

I'm trying to sort the folders disk usage in human readable format in RHEL 5.9.

I mounted the drive as NFS in Cent OS 6.4, where sort -h option works fine.

But in RHEL 5.9, it throws error as

> sort: invalid option -- h Try `sort --help' for more information.

Sort version in Cent OS is sort (GNU coreutils) 8.4 and in Redhat it's sort (GNU coreutils) 5.97.

Are there any options to update the sort version in Redhat?

Comment: You could work around this using one of the alternative answers to this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/62411/how-can-i-sort-du-h-output-by-size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5, no. Unless Red Hat releases an enhancement to the package that provides the `sort` binary, the "human readable sort" behavior will never appear in any RHEL 5 point release. You may be able to install a RHEL 6 package to get this behavior, but I strongly recommend against doing so.